# Why does StackExchange.Redis throw "No connection is available" when running in NUnit?

Tags: redis, nunit

Please consider the following code that uses the [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) .net library to connect to an [Azure Redis Cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/):

```
var url = "...";
var password = "...";

var connnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(
    $"{url}, abortConnect=false, ssl=true, password={password},
    connectTimeout=10000, syncTimeout=10000, name=RedisCache");

var database = connnection.GetDatabase();

database.StringSet("some_key", "some_value");
```

When I run the code in a console application it works fine. When I run it inside an NUnit test it fails with this exception:

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException : No connection is available to service this operation: SET some_key
>      at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor'1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
>      at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor'1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
>      at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.StringSet(RedisKey key, RedisValue value, Nullable'1 expiry, When when, CommandFlags flags)

Why does this happen in NUnit and how can I fix it?

Comment: I opened a new issue at StackExchange.Redis GitHub repo: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1289